# How to implement wordpress login user via user id

Tags: php, wordpress

I have being trying to implement wordpress login with just the user id.

Here is my code, but it does not work. The code does not log the user in.

```
// check if user has an account...
$details = get_user_by("email", $user->emailAddress);
//check user if not empty...
if ($details != null) {      
  // create a cookie and log user in...
  wp_set_current_user($details->ID, $details->user_login);
  wp_set_auth_cookie($details->ID);
  do_action('wp_login', $details->ID);

  //redirect to homepage...
  header("Location: " . site_url());
}
```

Comment: Change do_action('wp_login', $details->ID); intto this do_action('wp_login', $user->emailAddress);

Comment: @cgee i did it your way still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Well the documentation states that the function get_user_by() returns false on failure and user object in case of success but in your code you are checking for NULL, so perhaps you can try for this:

```
if (is_object($details)) {      
    //your code
}

or 

if ($details != false) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Well in that case try this code, coz if the email does not exists in the table then it will return boolean false:  if ($details != false) { //your code }

Comment: @hsharama the code gets base the if statement i did a check, thats the standard way to do it but its still does not work in my case.